# ASP.NET How to print a gridview without accesible header?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview, printing

I'm working in a ASP.NET/C# web project. I have a menu page with an iframe which displays a dynamic GridView element, a print button and a title-label, among others:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function abrirIfr(url) {
        $("#ifr1").attr("src", url);
    }
</script>

<iframe id="ifr1" src="" width="100%" height="550px" frameBorder="0" style="width: 100%; height: 480px"></iframe>
```

GridView, and other iframe's contents are included into another page:

```
    <div id="printTitle" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="lblTitulo" CssClass="text" runat="server" Text="" Font-Size="x-Large"></asp:Label>
    </div>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updFamiliares" runat="server" class="center">
    <ContentTemplate>

    <div runat="server" id="divFamiliares" class="text-center">
         <asp:GridView HeaderStyle-CssClass="text-center" HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" RowStyle-Wrap="false" runat="server" ID="grdFamiliares" BorderStyle="None" UseAccessibleHeader="True" CssClass="table table-condensed" Horizontal-Align="Center" OnRowDataBound="grdFamiliares_RowDataBound" OnPreRender="grdFamiliares_PreRender" visible="False">             
         </asp:GridView>
    </div>

   <div style="text-align:center">
       <asp:Button ID="btnPrint" runat="server" Text="Imprimir" OnClientClick="imprimir();"/>
   </div>

   </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Moreover, GridView contains accessibility features through an 'OnPreRender' event in code behind:

```
protected void grdFamiliares_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (grdFamiliares.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        if (grdFamiliares.HeaderRow != null)
        {
            grdFamiliares.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
        }
        if (grdFamiliares.FooterRow != null)
        {
            grdFamiliares.FooterRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter;
        }

    }
}
```

At the moment I'm trying to print some iframe's contents (only the dynamic GridView and the label element).

Is it possible to get a printout which only includes the GridView and the label items, hiding accessible-headers and print button? After print, can I return to the initial page's layout and show again the hidden elements in an easy way?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Do you mean with printing the process of creating output to paper? Because you have HTML, the easiest way would be to create custom print CSS with a `@media print { }` rule, which styles your HTML only when printing.

Comment: Thank you Niels; that's what I mean. Can `@media print{ }` rule be used in raw HTML? Because I shouldn't use HTML 5 in this joined project.

Comment: `@media print {}` needs to be used inside your CSS file, and is supported from FireFox 3.5, Internet Explorer 9, Chrome 14, Safari 3.2, Opera 11.
The old wat is to include a separate CSS print file with `<link href="/print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" type="text/css" />`